# How do I convert a HTML table to a fixed font textual table?

Tags: html, perl, text

I have an application in Perl that reads in HTML based mark up and converts it to a textual output.  One of the things I have encountered is the need to easily convert a HTML table to a fixed font output.

```
 <table border="1">
 <tr><td>Hello</td>
     <td>World</td>
 <tr>
     <td>foo</td>
     <td>bar</td>
 </tr></table>
```

I am looking for something that can take the above table and create something like the following.

```
 ------------------------------
 | Hello     | World          |
 ------------------------------
 | foo       | bar            |
 ------------------------------
```

I know how to approach this in Perl and write the process, but I am hoping that there is some library out there that already will do this for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used [Text::Table](http://search.cpan.org/~anno/Text-Table-1.114/lib/Text/Table.pm) with great success. In combination with something like [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~petek/HTML-Tree-3.23/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm) it should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

If available, I would use an external program like [lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser)), [links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_(web_browser)) or [w3m](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3m).  I don't know if any of them can handle arbitrary HTML thrown at them, though.